# Typescript with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I want to create a simple app using `Typescript` with `AngularJS 1.5` using `gulp`. I am using `Yeoman` generator. It can be a very basic `Hello World` app but it should use typescript with Angular.

Any pointers how should I begin with it? I searched a lot but couldn't find any source where such app is being told from scratch. How to create a basic directory structure with this stack of `TypeScript + Angular`?

Comment: angular fullstack generator supports typescript - https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack

Comment: You should start with angular2. All the docs are with typescript

Comment: this article will let you hit the ground running. https://chsakell.com/2015/09/19/typescript-angularjs-gulp-and-bower-in-visual-studio-2015/